# I'm Unable to add 'name' attribute to Accordion, AccordionSummary (Material UI component)?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui, cypress

For cypress test case, I need name attribute. I'm not able to give `name` attribute for *Accordion, AccordionSummary* which are UI Component in my application.

```
<AccordionSummary
  expandIcon={<ExpandMore className={classes.iconColor} />}
  aria-controls="sensors"
  id="sensors"
  //need name attribute here 
>
  <Typography>Sensors</Typography>
</AccordionSummary>
```

Comment: Why do you need `name` here? It is commonly used only in form elements. Are you trying to add `aria-label`?

Comment: Can you share the `AccordionSummary` component implementation, or if it's imported from a component library, specify/confirm which library it is so we can check it's API and implementation?

Comment: @MatthewKwong Thank you for information. Can i use aria-label instead of name attribute ?

Comment: @DrewReese I am using AccordianSummary from "@material-ui/core" library of Material UI.

Comment: The question is what are you trying to achieve in the first place? Why do you want to put `name` here? It has zero impact on the functionality and SEO unless you are placing this component in a `form` which I bet no one will be doing it.

Comment: @MatthewKwong For cypress test case, I need one unique identifier for Accordion like name and id. ID is not working for some test case scenario. My question is, is there any unique identifier in mateial-ui to identify component ?

Comment: Would a "data-x" attribute work more appropriately for the integration testing for identification/targeting purposes? I did a quick look over the v5 docs and didn't explicitly see a `name` prop exposed out in either the `AccordionSummary` nor the `ButtonBase` it extends. ***However***, MUI does tend to occasionally omit/neglect to document all a component's props so you'd need to dig in their source to see what props are accepted and what is done with them (*i.e. are certain extra props spread down*).